# Send email with PHP when domain is hosted by Media Temple and email is hosted by domains.live.com

Tags: php, email, smtp, dns

I have setup a simple form on my website to test sending email using PHP.

The form posts the input of three text fields to email-form-process.php, which looks like this:

```
<?php

    $email = $_POST['email'];

    $subject = "Test Email Worked";

    $msg = $_POST['comment'];

    mail ('$email','$subject','$msg');

    header('Location: email-form-confirm.php');
    exit();

?>
```

I echoed out the three inputs in a test to make sure email-form-process.php is receiving them from the form, which it is.

The problem I am having is that the email isn't being received at any of my emails. I have tested it going to a @live.com email and to two custom domains hosted by domains.live.com.

I use domains.live.com to host all of my email for my websites. I have my DNS records setup via my host, MediaTemple, for domains.live.com to handle my email. This works really great for regular email stuff, but I'm not sure what the best way is to send email in PHP using my custom domain emails hosted by domains.live.com.

**How do I send email from me@mydomain.com via PHP when my domain is hosted by MediaTemple and my email is hosted by domains.live.com?**

I have not tried using the SMTP method yet. Would the solution found at the following link be a good direction for me to go? http://www.9lessons.info/2009/10/send-mail-using-smtp-and-php.html

Thank you in advance for any help you can offer!

-Mark

Comment: Have you asked MT's support if they have sendmail setup and configured? If it is, you should be able to send mail from any email domain. In fact, `phpinfo()` should be able to tell you if it's available.

Comment: Also, if that PHP page is not protected somehow (users have to be logged in), you may have a spam script waiting to happen.

Comment: Thanks Jared. I checked phpinfo() and sendmail_form has 'no value' and sendmail_path does have a path. SMTP is also set to 'localhost'. What should I be looking for? When I contact MediaTemple, what should I ask them? Thanks, again!

Comment: I'm not sure about sendmail_form (my Dreamhost doesn't have anything there either), but it does have a path. I can't test it at the moment to see if it sends, but I could when I had several MT-hosted sites, and we didn't have anything special setup. Contact their support and just tell them what's going on; ask about any logs you can check and whether they have a test script which could prove whether it works or not. They're usually pretty helpful (if slow at times).

Answer (score 4):

If you're hosting mail elsewhere, you'll need to disable local mail for your server.

http://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/519/How+to+enable+or+disable+local+mail+for+your+server%3F

Answer (score 0):

Because Live is hosting your email, it may be blocking/sending the incoming emails immediately to spam folder. Your web server has a different IP than live's email server, so it might think it is sending bogus emails.

You might also want to look into sendgrid; they put your server IP on a whitelist and your emails will DEFINITELY get through.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Eric. I will keep sendgrid in mind as I work through finding a good overall solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like PHPMailer which will make it a LOT easier to use SMTP mail. That is definitely a better solution overall anyway than using the built in mail command in PHP as PHPMailer gives you much better attachment handling, recipient handling, etc. without having to write your own headers to send through the mail function.

You could also send from MediaTemple's server and just set the host name as your domain. It doesn't have to match the MX record although spam filters take notice of that and so you'll need to configure your domain for SenderID and SPF at the minimum so that the MediaTemple host is seen as a valid email sender for your domain.